# Alamofire post serialization error

Tags: http-post, alamofire, swift4

I am trying to make a HTTP Post using alamofire, below is my code:

```
@IBAction func loginUserBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let urlAddress = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/xx/xx/xx/login"
    let pass = Array(userPassword.text!)
    let username = userEmail.text!

    let params : [String: Any] = ["username": username, "pwd":  pass]
    print(params)

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]


    Alamofire.request(urlAddress, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{

        responds in
        if responds.result.isSuccess{
            print("Succesfull")

            let LoginJSON : JSON = JSON(responds.result.value!)
            //self.updateWeatheData(json: weatherJSON)
            print(LoginJSON)
        }
        else{
            print("Error \(String(describing: responds.result.error))")


        }
    }

}
```

This is the error I'm getting but if I change responseJSON to responseString I get a success, but the server is rejecting my data.

Here is my error message:

Error Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

Comment: The error message is saying that the response is not a valid JSON, so Alamofire cannot deserialize the response. Very probably the server is responding with some sort of errors, can be html. What do you get when you use `responseString`?

Comment: you can check your request response through the postman application

Answer (score 0):

```
encoding: URLEncoding.default
```

I see what you have header of content-type is JSON, but Encoding field inform in what type your params. Try this:

```
encoding: JSONEncoding.default
```